# Deleting all pointers to same object

Tags: c++

I have something like this:

```
void foo(){
Student *a0 = new Student();
Student *a1 = new Student();
Student *a2 = new Student();
Student *a3 = new Student();
}
```

I have another function

```
void foo2(){
Student* delStudent;
delStudent = ll.ReturnStudentToDelete(); //this function returns a pointer to delete student
delete delStudent ;
delStudent = NULL;
}
```

suppose, `ll.ReturnStudentToDelete()` returns address of `a2`, above code deletes this object. I want also to set pointer 'a2' to NULL. But I don't know how to retrieve a2 pointer so that to set it to NULL.

Currently I have 2 pointers (a2 and selStudent) which point to same object

Also, I was asked to use `operator*() and operator->()`. But I didn't get that at all, so I try to do my best. Could you please post simple template example of how that may be implemented. I understand that above raw pointers are bad to use

Comment: I assume `foo()` doesn't actually exist in the form you posted it here, because as you posted it, it does nothing except generate memory leaks.

Comment: you know that you dont have to mess around with manual dynamic memory, right? You can either use smartpointers or even simpler dont use dynamically allocated memory

Comment: 99.9% of the task in c++ can be performed without using raw pointer

Comment: There is no way to "reach out" into the universe of variables and modify those that happen to hold a particular value. This situation often follows from overuse of pointers and underthinking about ownership.

Comment: imho the quesiton lacks an explanation of why you want to do that. Having raw owning pointers is no fun and results in many comments about not using them ;)

Comment: It seems like you want a single `std::shared_ptr<Student>` per `Student` with a bunch of `std::weak_ptr<Student>`. Though that sounds like it may be the result of poor design decisions.

Comment: @user463035818 , Is there any simple template you can post of how above code can be implemented with smart pointers? I was asked to use operator*() and operator->(), but i couldn't , so i do best i can

Comment: `I want also to set pointer 'a2' to NULL` Then make sure you pass a reference to `a2` pointer

Comment: no i cannot, because it is not completely clear what you actually want to do. Moreover the code you do show cannot work like you describe (see answer from MrFox)

Comment: Use `std::shared_ptr` instead. That's what they are for. The first code snippet does not create multiple pointers to the same object.

Comment: Describe what you actually want to do. It is very, very unlikely that the best way to do it involves operator `new` or pointers, smart or otherwise. Try to forget that you ever heard of `new`.

Comment: I gonna do operations with 5 files , at any time in memory there should be no more than 3 files. So I have to use pointers in order to manipulate those pointers to files

Answer (score 3):

Based on your code, since you do this:

```
void foo(){
    Student *a0 = new Student();
    ...
}
```

Actually, you never store the pointers. In fact this means that when you call `foo` you will instantly leak all of the memory you create, because you have not stored these pointers. Not only can the `ll.ReturnStudentToDelete()` function not get the `a2` pointer, it won't be able to get any relevant pointer.

You should start with seeing if you can avoid using a pointer. For example, perhaps your code could work like this:

```
Student someStudent;
...
someStudent.doSomething();
```

Or if you really do need a group of students:

```
std::vector<Student> groupOfStudents;
```

Comment: I would add that in general, it is very important to think about ownership, weak pointer use etc. at the design phase. But to some extent, using smart pointers allows you to allocate memory and have it deallocated when the last owner dies. This is similar to how you do it in Java and other garbage collected languages, but RAII and smart pointers can give you the efficiency of manual memory management. RAII is a beautiful thing in general!